# What does this do and can I achieve the same with vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the code:

```
$('<div/>').text($.trim(myId.val())).html();
```

I get that `myId` is a jQuery object, and I'm getting the value. I get that the value is being trimmed.

I suspect a random jQuery `div` object is being created, given the trimmed value from `myId` and then having done this, gotten back again by the `html()` method. The end result is some kind of formatted version of the value from `myId`.

The question is why? Is there any way to achieve the same using vanilla JavaScript?

---

EDIT: Really appreciating the insights. My bad form here adding a coda, but does this achieve the same?

```
goog.string.htmlEscape(goog.string.trim(goog.dom.forms.getValue(myId)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this does is HTML escapes the value of `myId.val()`, removing any leading and trailing whitespace.

As you already noted, `$.trim(myId.val())` just removes any leading and trailing whitespace.

It sets a "dummy" div with the text value of `$.trim(myId.val())`, which means that it is the literal value of it (no HTML escapes).

When you call `.html()` on a jQuery element with no arguments, you get back the HTML escaped value of the child nodes (in this instance, the text you just inserted). For example, in HTML ampersands have special meaning as character escapes, so a literal ampersand needs to be represented in an escaped form (`&amp;`).

Using plain JavaScript, this would be equivalent to the following:

```
var myId = document.getElementById('myid');
var a = document.createElement('div');

// probably an input field, original code uses val()
a.textContent = myId.value.trim();
console.log(a.innerHTML);
```

Note that `String.prototype.trim` is an ES5 method, which means that older browsers (such as IE8 and older) may not this method natively. Also, `textContent` isn't cross-browser. In case of that, you could do this instead:

```
function trimString(arg) {
  var str = String(arg);
  return str.match(/[\x09-\x0D\x20\xA0\u1680\u2000-\u200A\u2028\u2029\u202F\u205F\u3000\uFEFF]*([\s\S]*?)[\x09-\x0D\x20\xA0\u1680\u2000-\u200A\u2028\u2029\u202F\u205F\u3000\uFEFF]*/)[1];
}

var myId = document.getElementById('myid');
var a = document.createElement('div');

// probably an input field, original code uses val()
var genericText = document.documentElement.textContent ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';
a[genericText] = trimString(myId.value);
console.log(a.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Lovin' your work here. If you know any Google Closure, can you confirm or deny my question in the coda of the revised question?

Comment: @Nick: I'm not familiar with the library, but judging from the method names, seems to be the same idea.

Comment: Thanks. I thought so :)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: the `trimString` method will remove *all* whitespace from a string (e.g. `' Hello world '` > `'Helloworld'`). Trimming should only replace whitespace at the start and end of a string

Comment: Hey, mate. As a very well-educated Sydney-sider who has two kids older than you, I gotta say that whilst your tech skills may be awesome, you might want to steer clear of prose-editing people's questions. Unless your desire is to rid SO of any trace of idiosyncrasy or personality, that is :)

Comment: @Nick: yeah, sorry to say [we don't like any personality here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) :P (there's a bit of personality for ya). The main reason for the edit was to make clear that you wanted to see whether there was a feasible JavaScript alternative. Thanks though :)

Comment: More's the pity :)  In all seriousness, though, I do suggest you leave the editing to people with a greater feel for language and its nuances. All the best.

Answer (score 3):

It is called **Html-encoding**, and here these are your **Vanilla JavaScript** alternatives:

```
function htmlEncode(text) {
    var encodedText = text.replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
        .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
        .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
        .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
        .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
    return encodedText;
}
```

you can also can do it with a similar approach like:

```
function htmlEncode(text) {
    var txtNode = document.createTextNode(text);
    var txtdiv = document.createElement('div');
    txtdiv.appendChild(txtNode);
    return txtdiv.innerHTML;
};
```

Comment: Well technically it does more than that, but that's some of the things it does.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: thanks for your feedback, that's what I do, when I need it. Do I neglected something in it?

Comment: Actually, you're just missing `&nbsp;` -- I thought there were more. Since they aren't attributes, the escaping of `"` and `'` isn't required.

Answer (score 1):

That code gets you the **HTML-encoded** version of the value of `myId`

If the value of `myId` is `"<hello>"`, the above code returns `"&lt;hello&gt;"`

The same in vanilla JS would look like:

```
var elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.innerText = myId.value; // set as TEXT
console.log(elem.innerHTML); // get as HTML
```